# Sqoop MySQL Data import error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am new to Hadoop world. Just started learning the new things about hadoop.
I am getting below error while importing data from mysql to hdfs using sqoop:

```
sqoop:000> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/books --username root --password thanks --table authors --m 1;
Exception has occurred during processing command 
Exception: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException Message: startup failed:
groovysh_parse: 1: expecting EOF, found 'import' @ line 1, column 7.
   sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/books --username root --password thanks --table authors --m 1;
         ^    
1 error
```

Could you help me in fixing this error?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you are using sqoop2

you need to follow these steps!

**1st step** 
check if you have installed sqoop correctly

```
sqoop:000> show version --all
```

you should get a response something like this

```
Server version:   Sqoop 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT revision Unknown   Compiled by  
jarcec on Wed Nov 21 16:15:51 PST 2012 Client version:   Sqoop  
2.0.0-SNAPSHOT revision Unknown   Compiled by jarcec on Wed Nov 21 16:15:51 PST 2012   Protocol version:   [1]
```

**2nd step**

Check what connectors are available on your Sqoop server:

```
 sqoop:000> show connector --all 
 1 connector(s) to show: Connector with
 id 1:  
 Name: generic-jdbc-connector   
 Class:
 org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcConnector  
 Supported job
 types: [EXPORT, IMPORT]
```

**3rd step**

```
sqoop:000> create connection --cid 1  
Creating connection for connector  
with id 1  
Please fill following values to create new connection object  
Name: First connection  

Configuration configuration   
JDBC Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
JDBC Connection String: jdbc:mysql://mysql.server/database  
Username: sqoop  
Password: *****  
JDBC Connection Properties: There are currently  
0 values in the map: entry#  

Security related configuration options Max connections: 0 New  
connection was successfully created with validation status FINE and  
persistent id 1
```

**step 4**
now create a job for importing data
at the end it will also ask for extractore and loaders, use 1 as a value for both.

```
sqoop:000> create job --xid 1 --type import  
Creating job for  
connection with id 1 Please fill following values to create new job  
object  
Name: First job  
Database configuration  
Table name: users   
Table SQL statement: Table  
column names:  
Partition column name:  
 Boundary query:  

Output configuration  
Storage type:     
0 : HDFS Choose: 0   
Output directory: /user/jarcec/users   
New job was successfully created with  
validation status FINE and persistent id 1
```

**step 5**
now start the job

```
sqoop:000> start job --jid 1
```

and import your data

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass **--target-dir** argument `HDFS path` where sqoop should copy MySql records.
try:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/books --username root --password thanks --table authors --target-dir /mysqlCopy --m 1;
```

Comment: Where are you running it? Sqoop version? and can you explain me about groovysh_parse and sqoop:000?